# How to terminate time.sleep() after a signal is caught?

Tags: python, sleep

In Python 3.5, the behavior of `time.sleep(secs)` was changed:

> The function now sleeps at least `secs` even if the sleep is interrupted by a signal, except if the signal handler raises an exception
>
> (Source: [*time - Python Documentation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep))

Then, how can I make `time.sleep()` **not** sleep the remaining seconds after a signal handler returns as in Python 3.4 or below?

The solution I came up with is shown below. This example works perfectly but, in real codes, this is impractical because raising an exception can affect unwanted parts of code.

```
import signal
import time

class SleepInterruptException(Exception):
    pass

def signal_handler(signal, frame) -> None:
    raise SleepInterruptException()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

try:
    time.sleep(10)
except SleepInterruptException:
    pass
```

One of the workarounds of this problem may be unsetting the signal handler just after `time.sleep()` but it seems dirty. Is there any elegant way?

Comment: If you are in `sleep()` and have only one thread of control, the only part of code that can be affected by the exception is `sleep()` itself. Your solution looks robust and correct.

Comment: Sleep multiple times for a short interval, check for flag set by signal in between.

Comment: @DYZ Sorry my explanation was unclear. By "can affect unwanted parts of code", I meant raising an exception terminates `f()` if some function `f()` is called after the `try` block in the example. Wrapping `f()` inside (another) `try` doesn't help since it still cancels the execution of `f()`. `f()` shall ideally completely ignores the exception.

Comment: @KlausD. It should work but dirtier IMHO.

Comment: I guess I am confused. If you call `f()` after the `try` block, it will not be affected by the signal.

Answer (score -2):

The default Python signal handler for SIGINT sets a Windows event object: sigint_event.

time.sleep() is implemented with WaitForSingleObjectEx(), it waits for the sigint_event object using time.sleep() parameter as the timeout. So the sleep can be interrupted by SIGINT.

_winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects() automatically adds sigint_event to the list of watched handles, so it can also be interrupted.